# Dragging two images using multi touch

Tags: xcode, image, drag, touches, multi-touch

I am fairly new to touch event and i have a problem. I use the code above to drag two images on screen. The code works however when the the second finger touches the screen the first movement stops. So, the problem is related to multi-touch. I also, do not know how to calculate the second touches co-ordinates. I enabled multitouch in the view and in both images. I would be great full if somebody could help me move each image with each finger. 
Thanks in advance!

```
-(void) touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
UITouch *touch = [[event allTouches] anyObject];
CGPoint location = [touch locationInView:self.view];
if ([touch view] == image) {
    image.center = location;
} else if ([touch view] == image2) {
    image2.center = location;
}}

-(void) touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
[self touchesBegan:touches withEvent:event];}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend using a custom [UIGestureRecognizer](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIGestureRecognizer_Class/Reference/Reference.html) for that. It will give you an nice encapsulated way to manage what you want. Dragging two images at the same time is in essence a gesture.

Comment: Thanks for the tip! It was much easier. I found this tutorial to be very helpful http://ios.biomsoft.com/2011/11/30/uigesturerecognizer-tutorial-in-ios-5-pinches-pans-and-more/